# How to stretch iOS views when adjacent views disappear?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 3 views adjacent next to each other: one in the center and two at top and bottom. At times I set the top and bottom views to hidden. How can I make the center view stretch when this happens?

Comment: you should override `layoutSubviews` in your parent view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to hard code the CGRects that get assigned to the views' frames when set hidden is called:

```
if (surroundingViewsHidden) {
    iphoneWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    ipadWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
}
else {
    iphoneWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 372);
    ipadWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 916, 768);
}
```

It gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

call this function after you have hide the other views

```
-(void) stretchView : (UIView *) view
{
    [view setFrame:self.view.frame];
}
```

eg, [self stretchView:viewForStretch];

(you can also apply animation while stretch the view)

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSArray` of the 3 (or more) `UIView`s, and call this method whenever you hide any of the views.  This method will allow any visible views to expand to fill the container.

```
-(void)expandVisibleViews{

NSUInteger numVisible = 0;
NSFloat height;
NSUInteger count = 0;

for(UIView *view in viewArray){
  if(!view.hidden){
    numVisible++;
  }
}

height = container.frame.size.height / numVisible;


for(UIView *view in viewArray){
  if(!view.hidden){
    view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height*count, view.frame.size.width, height);
    count++;
  }
}

}
```